# Usar ExecuteScalar dentro de una transacción en C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Estoy creando un módulo donde se harán varias inserciones y actualizaciones a algunas tablas de una base de datos, y estaba leyendo que usando

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO complemento_pago (uuid, monto, forma_pago, rfc_receptor) VALUES (@uuid, @monto, @formaPago, @rfcReceptor) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
```

Hace las dos operaciones: inserta en la tabla y me devuelve el identity generado.

el problema viene porque lo estoy intentando ejecutar dentro de una transacción, así que manda error

> System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteScalar requiere que el
>   comando tenga una transacción cuando la conexión asignada al mismo
>   está en una transacción local pendiente. No se ha inicializado la
>   propiedad Transaction del comando.
>
> en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method,
>   Boolean async)
>
> en
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, DbAsyncResult result)
>
> en
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)
>
> en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
>
> en Mantenimiento.CFDIs.PagaCFDIs(Comprobante _oComprobante) en
>   C:\respaldo\backup-sistema\Mantenimiento-Línea
>   original\Mantenimiento\Mantenimiento\CFDIs.cs:línea 214

Se que el problema se da porque está dentro de una transacción, porque cuando comento las líneas de BeginTransaction y Commit, las consultas se ejecutan sin problema. ¿Alguien podría decirme cómo solucionarlo?

¡Gracias por su apoyo!

**Edito para mayor claridad:**

La idea general del método es la siguiente:

```
private int PagaCFDIs(Comprobante _oComprobante)
{
    string sql = "INSERT INTO complemento_pago (uuid, monto, forma_pago, rfc_receptor) VALUES (@uuid, @monto, @formaPago, @rfcReceptor) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnect))
    {
       con.Open();

       using (SqlTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction())
       {
           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con, trans))
           {
               int x = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());       //Aquí es donde lanza el error

               sql = "select id from cfdis where uuid = @uuid";

               //Aquí hay más código para ejecutar el nuevo sql

               sql = "UPDATE CFDIs SET saldo_pendiente = @saldo_insoluto WHERE uuid = @uuid_relacionado AND estatus_cfdi = 1 AND saldo_pendiente <> 0; INSERT INTO cfdi_complemento (CFDI_FK, complemento_FK, monto_pagado, monto_pendiente) VALUES (@cfdiFk, @complementoFk, @montoPagado, @montoPendiente);"

               //Aquí hay más código para ejecutar el nuevo sql

               //Más abajo se actualizan tablas y se realizan otras operaciones

               trans.Commit();     //Finalizo la transacción si todo salió bien
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes una transacción abierta tienes que asignársela al command. Ej:

```
cmd.Transaction = trans;
```

Si un command se ejecuta sin esa propiedad en una conexión que tiene transación abierta te dará ese error.
Si no le has pasado la transacción al método, tienes que pasársela para poder asignarla.

La respuesta de Roger es correcta, el asigna la transaccion en el constructor del command si te fijas.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @bsebe, modifiqué mi pregunta a ver si así queda más claro lo que estoy intentando.

Comment: Gracias @bsebe por tu respuesta, no la había entendido bien, pero leyendo y leyendo comprendí a qué te refieres. Ya puedo seguir adelante con mi trabajo. Saludos!!!

Comment: No hay de qué, me alegra haber podido ayudarte @antonio-veneroso-contreras

Answer (score 2):

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO complemento_pago (uuid, monto, forma_pago, rfc_receptor) VALUES (@uuid, @monto, @formaPago, @rfcReceptor) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnect))
{
con.Open();
using (SqlTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction())
    {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con, trans))
        {
        int x = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        trans.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias Roger por tu respuesta, pero no me funciona. Como comenté, ya estoy dentro de una transacción. Si pongo otra transacción dentro marca error de que SQLConnection no permite transacciones anidadas.

Comment: Roger, modifiqué la pregunta, podría revisarla a ver si me puede ayudar?